# Extract everything to the left 2nd occurance of a character in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe column:

```
df: 
     Text
0 J Smith abc def
1 T Smith hij klm
2 A Smith xy z
```

I am hoping to extract everything before the 2nd space as a new column:

expected output:

```
    Text               Name
0 J Smith abc def       J Smith
1 T Smith hij klm       T Smith
2 A Smith xy z          A Smith
```

I have tried the following (some items in `Text` may be blank hence the if statement):

```
df['Name'] = df.Text.apply(lambda x: x.split(" ")[0:1]  if len(x) >0 else 0 )
```

But no such luck. Any ideas on how to get this working?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `Series.str.split` then grab the first 2 elements from the list with `str[:2]` and then join the strings back together with `str.join`:

```
df["Name"] = df["Text"].str.split(" ").str[:2].str.join(" ")

              Text     Name
0  J Smith abc def  J Smith
1  T Smith hij klm  T Smith
2     A Smith xy z  A Smith
```

Comment: Thanks! I just updated the original question as i forgot there are more spaces in the text. So when I tried it on my df it didnt quite work. Is there a tweak i could make?

Comment: So are there always 3 spaces or can that differ?

Comment: It can differ - but regardless I am after everything to the left of the 2nd space